# Media query being called when screen bigger

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been asked to do some tweaks in Wordpress for a friend, one of which is adding a little flowery flourish to his site. This was all going well until I encountered some media query problems.

When I put the queries in, to change the width of an element, they're all showing up in the inspector, but only the second one is being used - even though the max-width is smaller than the current screen size. It's like the code is being overwritten just like it would usually be if it weren't in a media query.

[Screenshot showing code, website with current screen size and inspector indicating current styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK97g.jpg)

I've put it through a validator to check that I wrote it right, have tried adding 'screen' to the query and adding 'min-width' to it too. So far, nothing is working. I'm sure it must be something silly I'm missing, any ideas?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #section-home-inner::before {
         width: 80%;
    }

    #section-home-inner::after {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 868px) {
    #logo img {
        max-height: 99px;
    }

    #section-home-inner::before {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: -230px;
    }

    #section-home-inner::after {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: -230px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` applied?

Comment: try-@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {...} & put <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> in head

Comment: make sure your browser is not zoomed . press cntrl + 0 to make it normal(100%). Secondaly make sure it has the responsive meta tag

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick responses! I'll double check the meta tag but one of the media queries does work because there is a difference to the logo... but actually that seems to be happening at the wrong screen width too - hmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

> In Css the style written below in the code always override the above
>   style. So in your code max-width: 868px is written below the
>   max-width: 1199px. Thats why max-width: 868px is overriding the style
>   and that is being seen. So change the code like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 868px) {
        #logo img {
            max-height: 99px;
        }

        #section-home-inner::before {
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: -230px;
        }

        #section-home-inner::after {
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: -230px;
        }
    }    

    @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
        #section-home-inner::before {
             width: 80%;
        }

        #section-home-inner::after {
            width: 80%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way round? Surely then 'max-width: 1199' will always be used? When I put it in it made the larger version work but not the one for width smaller than 868. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: you know what it should be @media screen and (min-width:869px) and (max-width: 1199px) in the first query. try it out.

Comment: Yeah I'd tried that before posting and just done again - not going well so far :/ I think things are being triggered at a different width to the page width - maybe its in an iframe or something and I just need to re-jig the width declarations...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something super silly! If you look in the screenshot I attached, you can see the customiser is open - this is obviously taken into account with the screen width, but the width of the actual site was much smaller. As a result, I'd calculated entirely the wrong breakpoints.... Luckily a fresh look at it after work and I realised exactly what I'd done wrong!

Thanks everyone for your help!!